# Bootstrap 3 - Division of columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Assume we have two rows:
1 Row with **col-md-12**
1 Row with 2 divs, each of **col-md-6**

In the first row, I have Label/Textbox in a form-horizontal way. An example is shown below.

My question is, does the div with class **form-group** give me a row of width 12 columns? How to align content when I have rows including columns of different width? For instance, I need to align the sub button to be aligned with the Textbox, not the Label.

I am realizing that when I use a div.form-group, then I get the chance to have new 12 columns, even though the div.form-group is inside a div.col-md-6. Is this correct?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtFirstName" class="control-label col-md-3 col-xs-3">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFirstName">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtLastName" class="control-label col-md-3 col-xs-3">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLastName">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check it http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to use class 'row' to make it into col-6 div.

```
<div class="col-xs-11 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"> 
              <label for="txtFirstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-8">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFirstName">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check http://getbootstrap.com/css/ , Nesting columns section

Comment: Maybe I am still not explaining myself well. check this sample. http://www.bootply.com/KCjIFRWQQI    When I place a row inside a div.col-md-6, I get a new 12 columns, hence the length of a column in the sub row is 1/2 length of the column inside parent row. Makes sense?

Comment: yes..sub-row is a length of col-6 size which equals to 1/2 length. Parent col-(?) class has nothing to do width size. So Whenever you have one 'row' class, make sure you sum upto 12 of the class-digits. for example, row can be divided into col-4 : col-3: col-5, col-3: col-3:col-6 and so on.